# use Dojo to detect if all checkboxes are unchecked, disable a button

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dojo, onchange

I have a group of checkboxes and a QUERY button so user can check a few things and click QUERY button to make a service call to return records. How to disable the QUERY button if none of the checkboxes are checked?

Below are the codes I wrote. The QUERY button got disabled when I first time unchecked all of them. But when I checked only one of checkboxes back again, the array "unchecked" became empty. please help!

```js
      _bindChkChangeEvent: function(){
            var unchecked = []; 
            on(query('.chk'), 'change', lang.hitch(this, function(event) {
                if(!event.target.checked){
                    if(unchecked.indexOf(event.target.id) < 0)
                        unchecked.push(event.target.id);
                }
                else{
                    if(unchecked.indexOf(event.target.id) > -1)
                        unchecked.splice(event.target.id);
                }
 
                this._switchQueryBtn(unchecked); 
            }));
        },

        _switchQueryBtn: function(unchecked){
             if(unchecked.length == 10)
                    html.addClass(this.btnQuery, 'disabled');
             else
                    html.removeClass(this.btnQuery, 'disabled');
        },
```

Comment: worked after I made the follow changes: unchecked.splice(event.target.id); to unchecked.splice(unchecked.indexOf(event.target.id), 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the following link a working example, you can try to adopt this concept to your code (unfortunately the question contains only a partial code view).

https://jsfiddle.net/zmh7bbrf/

What the script does:

- Create two checkboxes programmatically.
- Create a button programmatically.
- Add event handler `onChange` for each checkbox.
- Function `showHideButton` actually contains the logic to show or hide the button.
- Now when the page load, both checkboxes are unchecked, `showHideButton` runs and button is being disabled.
- When User click on a checkbox, re-run function `showHideButton`.
- At this point condition is not met, as one checkbox is checked now, so re-enable the button.

The script could work with any number of checkboxes, just add their reference and modify the logic in `showHideButton` function.

Notes:
You can use `dijit/registry` to find references of your widgets, instead of using `dojo/query` and querying the DOM directly as in the code in your original question.

More information on `dijit/registry` can be found here:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/registry.html

---

```
require(["dijit/form/CheckBox", "dijit/registry", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!"], function(CheckBox, registry, Button) {
  new CheckBox({
    id: "checkBox0",
    name: "checkBox0",
    value: "option0",
    checked: false,
    onChange: function(event) {
      showHideButton();
    }
  }, "checkBox0").startup();
  new CheckBox({
    id: "checkBox1",
    name: "checkBox1",
    value: "option1",
    checked: false,
    onChange: function(event) {
      showHideButton();
    }
  }, "checkBox1").startup();
  new Button({
    label: "Click me!",
    onClick: function() {;
    }
  }, "button").startup();

  var showHideButton = function() {
    var checkBox0 = registry.byId('checkBox0'),
      checkBox1 = registry.byId('checkBox1'),
      button = registry.byId('button');
    if (!checkBox0.checked && !checkBox1.checked) {
      button.set('disabled', true);
    } else {
      button.set('disabled', false);
    }
  };
  showHideButton();

});
```

---

```
<input id="checkBox0" />
<label for="checkBox">Option 0</label>
<br>
<input id="checkBox1" />
<label for="checkBox">Option 1</label>
<br>
<button id="button" type="button"></button>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I see the idea of your code. But for my case, I have a dozen of checkboxes, querying checkboxes by the class and then loop through them seem easier.

Comment: @AlexW I understand your point, alternatively you can use registry.toArray() to loop thought all you widgets and select only the checkboxes checked and applying your logic there.